# How to upgrade Strapi in Docker container?

Tags: docker, strapi

I launched [Strapi](https://strapi.io) with Docker-compose. After reading the [Migration Guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/migration-guide/), I still don't know if I wanna upgrade to the next version, what method should I choose:

1. Under to the Strapi project directory, execute `npm install strapi@<next version> -g` and `npm install strapi@<next version> --save`
2. `docker exec -it <strapi container> sh`, navigate to Strapi project directory, then execute `npm install strapi@<next version> -g` and `npm install strapi@<next version> --save`
3. Neither?

Comment: You seem to have two questions. A) Should I upgrade? B) How should I upgrade?  I think you'll need to provide more information to get an answer to A and probably one very specific issue would be better to ask rather than general advice. For B, I think you may also need to explain more about your configuration.

Answer (score 3):

1. In your local developer tree, update the package version in your `package.json` file.  Run `npm install` or `yarn install` locally.  Start your application.  Verify that it works.  Run your tests.  Fix any compatibility issues from the upgrade.  Do all of this without Docker involved at all.
2. Re-run `docker build .` to rebuild your Docker image with the new package dependencies.
3. Stop the old container, delete it, and run a new container with the new image.

As a general rule you should never install anything in a running container.  It's extremely routine to delete containers, and when you do, anything in the container will be lost.

There's a common "pattern" of running Node in Docker, bind-mounting your application into it, and then mounting an anonymous volume over your `node_modules` directory.  For routine development I've found it vastly simpler to just install Node on my host (it is literally a single `apt-get install` or `brew install` command).  If you're using this Docker-oriented setup, the anonymous volume for `node_modules` won't notice that you've changed your `node_modules` directory, and you have to re-run `docker build` and delete and recreate your containers.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: 3, while 2 was going in the right direction.

Official documentation wasn't clear for the first time for me either.
Below is a spin-off step-by-step guide from 3.0.5 to 3.1.5 in docker-compose context.

It tries to follow official documentation as close as possible, but includes a some extra (mandatory in my case) steps.

> ### Upgrade Strapi
>
> - Following relates to `strapi/strapi` (not `strapi/base`) docker image used via `docker-compose`
> - **Important!** Upgrading Docker image versions DOES NOT upgrade Strapi version.
>
>   - Strapi NodeJS application builds itself during first startup only, if detects empty folder and is normally stored in mounted volume. See [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/blob/master/strapi/docker-entrypoint.sh).
> - To upgrade, first follow the guides ([general](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/update-version.html) and [version-specific](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/migration-guide/)) to rebuild actual Strapi NodeJS application. Secondly, update docker tag to match the version to avoid confusion.
>
> Example of upgrading from 3.0.5 to 3.1.5:

```sh
# https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/update-version.html

# Make sure your server is not running until the end of the migration
## That is unclear instruction. Stopped Nginx to prevent access to application, without stopping Strapi itself. 
docker-compose exec strapi bash # enter running container
## Alternative way would be `docker-compose stop strapi` and manually reconstruct container options using `docker`, overriding entrypoint with `--entrypoint /bin/bash`

# Few checks
yarn strapi version # current version installed
yarn info strapi #npm info strapi@3.1.x version # available versions
yarn --version #npm --version
yarn list #npm list
cat package.json

# Upgrade your dependencies
sed -i 's|"3.0.5"|"3.1.5"|g' package.json && cat package.json
yarn install #npm install
yarn strapi version

  # Breaking changes? See version-specific migration guide!

  ## https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/migration-guide/migration-guide-3.0.x-to-3.1.x.html
    ## Define the admin JWT Token
    ## Update username constraint for administrators
    docker-compose exec db bash
    psql strapi strapi
      -- show tables and describe one
      \dt
      \d strapi_administrator
    ## Migrate your custom admin panel plugins

# Rebuild your administration panel
rm -rf node_modules # workaround for "Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve"
yarn build --clean #npm run build -- --clean

  # Extensions?

# Start your application
yarn develop #npm run develop
# Confirm & test, visit URL

  # Errors?

  ## Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, ...
  # Can be solved by modifying kernel parameter at docker HOST system
  sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf # fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
  sudo sysctl -p

# Modify docker-compose to reflect version changed and avoid confusion !
docker ps
vi docker-compose.yml # e.g. 3.0.5 > 3.1.5
docker-compose up --force-recreate --no-deps -d strapi
# ... and remove old docker image, when no longer required.
```

P.S. We may together improve documentation via https://github.com/strapi/documentation. Made a pull request https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/pull/276